# python normaliser not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, csv, fastapi

This is the code of normalizer

```
import csv

from app.models.data_source import DataSource
from . import normalize_fieldname
import logging

class NormalizingDictReader:
    """ csv DictReader which makes all keys lowercase, and replaces all dashes, spaces, and double underscores with single underscores"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        datasource = kwargs.pop('datasource', None)
        delimiter = kwargs.pop('delimiter', '|')
        kwargs.setdefault('dialect', 'piped')

        csv.register_dialect(
            'piped',
            delimiter=delimiter,
            # quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
            )
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(*args, **kwargs)
        self.reader.fieldnames = self.rename_fieldnames(
            self.normalize_fieldnames(self.reader.fieldnames), datasource)

    def normalize_fieldnames(self, fieldnames):
        logging.warning(f"_________fieldnames________{fieldnames}")
        return list(map(normalize_fieldname, fieldnames))

    def rename_fieldnames(self, fieldnames=[], datasource: DataSource = None):
        """ Rename the csv fieldnames as needed based on the given datasource """
        if not datasource:
            return fieldnames

        rename_lookup = {
            normalize_fieldname(field.name): field.normalized_name()
            for field in datasource.source_fields
        }

        # This is our primary key and people can't decide what to call it so
        # this is a failsafe to prevent borkenness
        rename_lookup['npi'] = 'npi_id'

        return [rename_lookup.get(name, name) for name in fieldnames]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.reader.__next__()
```

problem: whenever i upload the data there is two trigger `6M Treated 3L+ New` and `6M Treated 3L+ Contd`  in same file and its renaming to `2L+ FL Diagnosis`. first its renaming to `6M Treated 3L+ Contd` and then `6M Treated 3L+ New` but its overriding data first data to second and its showing data for only `6M Treated 3L+ New`. what i want is if the data is common like 0 or 1 or any the highest value should be considered .

Sample datasource data:

```
[DataSourceField(id=300, name='6M Treated 3L+ New', rename_to='2L+ FL Diagnosis', data_type='number', is_trigger=True, created_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 19, 8, 20, 18, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)),DataSourceField(id=301, name='6M Treated 3L+ Contd', rename_to='2L+ FL Diagnosis', data_type='number', is_trigger=True, created_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 19, 8, 20, 18, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))]
```

sample csv data:

```
[{'Id': '41526345', 'Timestamp': '12/25/2022', 'Title': '', 'First_Name': 'ALEXANDRIA', 'Middle_Name': '', 'Last_Name': 'COBB', 'Suffix': '', 'Designation': '', 'Phone': '', 'Address': '5008 Brittonfield Parkway', 'City': 'Syracuse', 'State': 'New York', 'Zip': '13057', 'Client_Group_Category': 'Physician Group', 'OS_ID': '41526345', 'NPI_ID': '1821335704', 'Email_1': '', 'Email_2': '', 'Specialty': 'Physician Assistant', 'Decile': '', 'Decile_Definition': '', 'Segment': '', 'Affiliation': 'Hem Onc Assoc of Central NY-Brittonfield', 'DLBCL_Unique_Count': '0', 'DLBCL_RR_Count': '0', 'FL_Unique_Count': '1'}, {'Id': '41526346', 'Timestamp': '12/25/2022', 'Title': '', 'First_Name': 'AMANDA', 'Middle_Name': '', 'Last_Name': 'HERRMANN', 'Suffix': '', 'Designation': '', 'Phone': '', 'Address': '6411 Fannin S3:202 Robertson Pavilion', 'City': 'Houston', 'State': 'Texas', 'Zip': '77030', 'Client_Group_Category': 'Hospital', 'OS_ID': '41526346', 'NPI_ID': '1518520402', 'Email_1': '', 'Email_2': '', 'Specialty': 'Student in an Organized Health Care Education/Training Program', 'Decile': '', 'Decile_Definition': '', 'Segment': '', 'Affiliation': 'Memorial Hermann Texas Medical Center', 'DLBCL_Unique_Count': '0', 'DLBCL_RR_Count': '0', 'FL_Unique_Count': '0'}, {'Id': '41526347', 'Timestamp': '12/25/2022', 'Title': '', 'First_Name': 'UMERA', 'Middle_Name': '', 'Last_Name': 'THEBO', 'Suffix': '', 'Designation': '', 'Phone': '', 'Address': '6720 Bertner Avenue Pathology Department Attn: Frank Sanchez', 'City': 'Houston', 'State': 'Texas', 'Zip': '77030', 'Client_Group_Category': 'Hospital', 'OS_ID': '41526347', 'NPI_ID': '1851637532', 'Email_1': '', 'Email_2': '', 'Specialty': 'Internal Medicine', 'Decile': '', 'Decile_Definition': '', 'Segment': '', 'Affiliation': 'CHI St Lukes Episcopal Medical Center-HemePath', 'DLBCL_Unique_Count': '0', 'DLBCL_RR_Count': '0', 'FL_Unique_Count': '1'}]
```